# How to parse Directions API Response from my middleware in android?

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, google-directions-api

how do I parse the API response of Google Directions API to draw a route from my point A to point B? I get my API response from my web's middleware. Do I need to create a POJO for this? is RoboPOJOgenerator a good one to use in making POJO from json? This json is the response from my okhttp logger.

```
{
"data":[
  {
     "bounds":{
        "northeast":{
           "lat":14.5845178,
           "lng":121.0601253
        },
        "southwest":{
           "lat":14.5722047,
           "lng":121.0535383
        }
     },
     "copyrights":"Map data \u00a92019",
     "legs":[
        {
           "distance":{
              "text":"2.0 km",
              "value":2013
           },
           "duration":{
              "text":"11 mins",
              "value":638
           },
           "end_address":"J Vargas Bus Stop, Epifanio de los Santos, Ortigas Center, Mandaluyong, Metro Manila, Philippines",
           "end_location":{
              "lat":14.5845178,
              "lng":121.0569895
           },
           "start_address":"14/F Robinsons Cybergate Tower 1 Pioneer St. Metro Manila, Philippines",
           "start_location":{
              "lat":14.5722047,
              "lng":121.0540196
           },
           "steps":[
              {
                 "distance":{
                    "text":"70 m",
                    "value":70
                 },
                 "duration":{
                    "text":"1 min",
                    "value":13
                 },
                 "end_location":{
                    "lat":14.5725109,
                    "lng":121.0545851
                 },
                 "html_instructions":"Head <b>northeast</b> on <b>Pioneer St</b> toward <b>Reliance St</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by HMR Trading Haus (on the left)</div>",
                 "polyline":{
                    "points":"gc}wAsjzaV]q@Ug@IW"
                 },
                 "start_location":{
                    "lat":14.5722047,
                    "lng":121.0540196
                 },
                 "travel_mode":"DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance":{
                    "text":"0.2 km",
                    "value":210
                 },
                 "duration":{
                    "text":"1 min",
                    "value":42
                 },
                 "end_location":{
                    "lat":14.5741085,
                    "lng":121.0535383
                 },
                 "html_instructions":"Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Reliance St</b>",
                 "maneuver":"turn-left",
                 "polyline":{
                    "points":"ee}wAenzaVmBhAmAp@cCtA"
                 },
                 "start_location":{
                    "lat":14.5725109,
                    "lng":121.0545851
                 },
                 "travel_mode":"DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance":{
                    "text":"0.6 km",
                    "value":573
                 },
                 "duration":{
                    "text":"3 mins",
                    "value":159
                 },
                 "end_location":{
                    "lat":14.5780025,
                    "lng":121.0569962
                 },
                 "html_instructions":"Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Sheridan</b>",
                 "maneuver":"turn-right",
                 "polyline":{
                    "points":"eo}wAsgzaVU_@Yg@GKKKECeCwB_ByAu@s@YWuAcAqCmB[UWQ}@o@o@g@"
                 },
                 "start_location":{
                    "lat":14.5741085,
                    "lng":121.0535383
                 },
                 "travel_mode":"DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance":{
                    "text":"0.8 km",
                    "value":829
                 },
                 "duration":{
                    "text":"6 mins",
                    "value":336
                 },
                 "end_location":{
                    "lat":14.5843678,
                    "lng":121.0599721
                 },
                 "html_instructions":"Continue onto <b>San Miguel Ave</b>",
                 "polyline":{
                    "points":"og~wAg}zaVOi@OMYWKGq@e@KIm@a@[SYSCAy@k@}@m@WSe@_@WOeAw@]Uw@m@}BgBKGQKMCMCM@S?_@BQ@G?y@BkAFw@?S?YBq@@S@}AB"
                 },
                 "start_location":{
                    "lat":14.5780025,
                    "lng":121.0569962
                 },
                 "travel_mode":"DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance":{
                    "text":"0.3 km",
                    "value":331
                 },
                 "duration":{
                    "text":"1 min",
                    "value":88
                 },
                 "end_location":{
                    "lat":14.5845178,
                    "lng":121.0569895
                 },
                 "html_instructions":"Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Do\u00f1a Julia Vargas Ave</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Destination will be on the right</div>",
                 "maneuver":"turn-left",
                 "polyline":{
                    "points":"io_xAyo{aVS@?PAd@?b@?\\AxEA`A?RA\\AlB?Z"
                 },
                 "start_location":{
                    "lat":14.5843678,
                    "lng":121.0599721
                 },
                 "travel_mode":"DRIVING"
              }
           ],
           "traffic_speed_entry":[

           ],
           "via_waypoint":[

           ]
        }
     ],
     "overview_polyline":{
        "points":"gc}wAsjzaVs@yAIWmBhAqEfCo@gASWkC{BuCmCoB{AcGeEo@g@Oi@i@e@wByAsBuAsCqByGcF]S[GsAFaABkAFw@?m@BeABqBDAv@C|ICzD"
     },
     "summary":"Sheridan and San Miguel Ave",
     "warnings":[

     ],
     "waypoint_order":[

     ]
  }
],
"status":"SUCCESS"
}
```

That is my response coming from the middle ware, I cannot use this code below

```
 private String getRequestUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
    String str_org = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String mode = "mode=driving";
    String avoid = "avoid=tolls|highways";
    String param = str_org + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode + "&" + avoid;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + param + "&key=" + getString(R.string.API_KEY);

    return url;
}

private String requestDirection(String reqUrl) throws IOException {
    String responseString = "";
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        //Get the response result
        inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }

        responseString = stringBuffer.toString();
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStreamReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

because I am not accessing the Directions API in my mobile app, I access it through my web's middleware. I really need help I've been stuck with this problem for 3 days now. Sorry for asking too many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I parse the API response of Google Directions API to draw a route from my point A to point B?

The API response is an array of small trips. You can imagine it as Google maps app giving you some sort of feedback every time that you arrive at the end of each step. Otherwise, I think the API structure is quite clear and field names describe their meaning quite clear. Let me know if you need me to go over them in more detail.

I get my API response from my web's middleware. Do I need to create a POJO for this.

You should definitely use a POJO (in other words, a DTO) here. The data is clearly defined and structured and a java object is much easier to navigate and utilize than wandering around JsonNode's. You will also have to deal with lots of different scenarios when your user uses the navigation (changing route, losing connection, app going to sleep) so you will have to continuously re-query the said data to update the map. Not using POJO's would set you up for a LOT of trouble and smelly code.

Is RoboPOJOgenerator a good one to use in making POJO from json?

Personally I like to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate me the domain classes but your suggestion should also be able to do the same thing.

Comment: When I use the RoboPOJOgenerator, it creates different classes like legs, steps, bounds. Is it okay that they are not in a single class file?

Comment: that is the expected outcome. a "Leg" is a bigger chunk of a journey that you perform in a single means of transportation, aka "walk", "take a bus", "take a metro". It then contains smaller chunks, "Step"s which are the detailed directions. You very much need this data to be separated as that will have to go to different UI elements on the app and, quite possibly, have to be processed by different business logic.

Comment: Again you would find yourself passing a lot of unnecessary data around if you would stuff everything into a single class. Also, java json decoder GSON nor other alternatives would not be able to easily flatten such a complex json structure in a single class

Comment: Thank you for your help I am now using the roboPOJOgenerator and it works fine, now I can access the response of google direction API, what I need now is to plot that data into my google map.

Comment: Why is it saying 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String delivery.blitz.client.Model.OverviewPolyline.getPoints()' on a null object reference

even though there is points and overview polyline in my json response?

Comment: I think this question is beyond the scope of a comment section. Maybe one of the objects in the array comes with a null value breaking the entire loop. I think you should try to debug and find what exactly causes it. Is the point not parsed properly or maybe the data structure itself requires additional validation.

Comment: Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(**************)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(client)
                    .build();

if this is how i post my data, will it return a gson and not json?

Comment: Gson is google's library for parsing JSON. In the end, you are still working with the same JSON objects. The problem you are facing is that the sample data to generate classes is somewhat different from the real data and the generator did not account for a nullable property on a variable. Automatic JSON->POJO generators are good, but only as good as the source JSON that you pass them. Sometimes you have to do manual adjustments to account for unexpected situations.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3rsM4g1F this is my response now, you are right some fields are null